# Move tree view as a web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have enabled tree view in navigation. The tree view displays site content in a physical manner in left side. I want that same hierarchy way of site contents structure as a web part or custom app part on home page. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB web part to show tree view navigation into modern web part.

You may need to use PnP Treeview control in the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) to customize the web part.

Reference:

https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/14/tree-view-navigation-using-pnp-treeview-control-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/